# How can i make a user disable push notification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, onesignal

I have an ionic app with onesignal. Everything works just fine.
I only don't know how to program the following:

If a user wants to turn of Push Notifications in the app settings, what line do i have to add to this code so onesignal knows it should skip this user.

I've read about segments, tags & filters but i don't know how to place it in this code.

```
angular.module('starter')
.run(function) { 
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
 console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
};

window.plugins.OneSignal
 .startInit("0000-0000-0000-0000-0000", "123456789")
 .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
 .endInit();

};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the OneSignal `setSubscription(false)` method to turn notifications off for a user.

`window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(false);`

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i needed!